# Emacs lisp semicolon character?

Tags: emacs, elisp

It's a silly question, really.
I want to do

```
(position ?; "This is a test; or is it?")
```

Unfortunately, the font-lock is regex based,
so it highlights a part of the code as a comment.

What's the best way to handle this? At the moment, I've got either

```
(defconst semicolon (aref ";" 0))
(position semicolon "This is a test; or is it?")
```

or

```
(position 59 "This is a test; or is it?")
```

Comment: `(position ?\; "This is a test; or is it?")`

Comment: Excellent, @giordano! I don't know how it escaped me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should escape the semicolon with a backslash:

```
(position ?\; "This is a test; or is it?")
```